# Wrong charset in one column, the rest are fine?

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

I have an issue where in a form if I input special characters (e.g. åöä) they get rendered fine in my database. However, I also have a checkbox with a value that gets inputted into another column and these columns doesnt render it correctly.

Things I've tried:

```
mysqli_set_charset("utf8", $con);

$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

[image]

(first two characters are inputs ive entered, other column is a checkbox value)

html checkbox

[image] value

All files are utf8, html code is utf8, database is utf8.

I'm completely out of ideas at the moment.

Edit, solved: [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Comment: Your answers are here: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279)

Comment: See Mojibake in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .

Comment: @RickJames thanks! solved.